# AWS ALB different ingress rules for different url paths

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group, aws-elb

I have internet-facing AWS ALB. I must accept all HTTP traffic only from whitelist set of ip addresses. At the same time there's one exclusion for *mydomain.com/some_path* - it should accept HTTP traffic from all IPs (0.0.0.0/0).

*Am I on the right way trying to configure this logic with ALB? Should I use path condtions for this purpose?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that via ELB settings and you can't do that via security groups. One option would be to attach a Web Application Firewall (WAF) to the ELB and then create the appropriate IP matching rules there.

Comment: ^^ Mark B has your answer... Definitely not do-able with SG's alone... that would open all the entire server to for HTTP from all IP ranges

Comment: @MarkB sorry, we're using ALB instead of ELB. My bad

Comment: @VB_ I assumed you were using ALB since you were talking about different path rules. The answer is still the same.